# Optimizing a huge Union operation on many, large tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following problem at hand. I have 18 very large Oracle tables; each has a row count changing between 2 and 15 millions and additionally each table has around 450 columns. The tables have the same column types and structures. What I need is to unify these tables into a very large, single table as soon as they are generated as the result of other operations. While generating each of these tables, I use the following optimizations:

1) I use the Create Table command for each table, with hints "NOLOGGING PARALLEL 32 COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH". Our database server supports parallelism up to 32 units.

2)After the creation of each table, I run a "dbms_stats.gather_table_stats" on that table in order to optimize the execution path.

Now, the most basic thing which came to my mind was the following statement:

```
    CREATE TABLE UNIFIED_TABLE NOLOGGING PARALLEL 32 COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH AS
    (SELECT * FROM TABLE_0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 ...

     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM TABLE_17
      )
```

This command doesn't look like that it would complete in an hour; it keeps running and running, so I need a more efficient way.

Currently I have the following in my mind: I would generate my final table as the copy of TABLE_0 in the beginning. Then I would make 17 additional, parallel calls from the application to the database server, each of which contains the following command:

```
INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE 
SELECT * FROM TABLE_i
```

I hope that since the database server supports parallelism, Oracle will handle parallel insertions from different INSERT INTO statements into the same table gracefully.

Would this be a good strategy to begin with? How can I optimize this unification task in the best way, are there any other better options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each tables data (id) is over a distinct range, create an empty partitioned table with the same structure as the 17 tables. Create empty partitions for the ranges corresponding to each table. Then SWAP/EXCHANGE the tables with the appropriate partition.

This, being DDL will be very quick.

If the data is not "ranged", add a column as the partition key (e.g. table_no).

Comment: My data is not exactly ranged, but actually each of the separate tables corresponds to a different entity, so I can add a column as a partition key. So, then, I should generate a partitioned table and load each table into the final partition, is that right? Why is this more efficient than regular INSERT INTO or UNION operations?

Comment: I cant remember the exact commands, but basically you create a table part_table with part_0, part_1,..... The table should be empty (no data). Then once you have created/loaded your tables table_0, table_1, ...., you then "ALTER TABLE part_table
EXCHANGE PARTITION part_0 WITH TABLE table_0". The reason this is quicker is because Oracle is not doing a data copy/move, it is simply switching some data dictionary pointers. A bit like when you RENAME a table. Read up on an example here http://www.orafaq.com/node/2570 . Once you've swapped, the table_0 etc will be empty so can be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider partition exchange?

This would work if you no longer have use for the 18 tables.
In this case you would truncate your final table, and switch the empty partition with the corresponding table_XX.